# linux driver development: unknown type name `__no_sanitize_or_inline` in file `linux/init.h`

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I've looked around Stack Overflow and none of the answers to similar topics ended up helping me; it seems like such a random issue no one else has. What I need is the compile_flags.txt to put in so I stop getting that type error and can actually get intellisense with clangd, compilation of the module works fine. Can anyone help?

My current compile_flags.txt looks like this:

```
-Iheaders
-I/usr/src/kernels/5.17.11-300.fc36.x86_64/include
-Wall
-O2
-std=gnu17
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you also show your errors?

Comment: Your list of compiler flags is definitely incomplete. You could build some kernel module using additional `V=1` parameter to the `make`: that way you will see the complete command lines used to compile.

Comment: Showing my ignorance, I do Linux kernel development but have never heard  of using a compile_flags.txt file.

Comment: @JustinYu as stated in the title, the error is `unknown type name '__no_sanitize_or_inline` in line `#include <linux/init.h>`